# Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership script is not removing user

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have the following script that runs without error but it doesn't remove the user from the group.  I am not sure what I am missing. I have tried running this without the username variable and with an actual name but that did not work either.  Thanks in advance for the help.

```
$group = @(
'Aberdeen Refer Team','Air Force Refer Team','Coliseum Refer Team','Denbigh Refer Team','Warwick Refer Team','Wards Corner Refer Team',
'Eagle HarborRefer Team','Chesapeake Refer Team','Willow Oaks Refer Team','poquoson Refer Team','Oyster Point Refer Team','NASA ReferTeam',
"Contact Center Refer Team",'Yorktown Refer Team','WB New Town Refer Team','WB City Refer Team','Stoneybrook Refer Team',
'Hayes Refer Team','Hilltop Refer Team')

$user = Get-aduser "%username%" -Properties MemberOf
if ($user.MemberOf -match $group)
{
    foreach ($group in $user)
    {
Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -identity $user -MemberOf $group -confirm:$False
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `%username%` with `$env:USERNAME` to get the username, and then find all the user's groups with [`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617259.aspx):

```
$TeamNames = @('Aberdeen Refer Team','Hilltop Refer Team')

$User = Get-ADUser "$($env:USERNAME)"

# Find all the groups that the user is a member of, and filter down to just those in the $TeamNames list
$UserGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user | Where-Object { $TeamNames -contains $_.Name }

# Iterate over the groups
foreach ($Group in $UserGroups)
{
    # Remove each group membership from the user
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $User -MemberOf $Group -Confirm:$false
}
```